# How do I calculate two dates and return a numeric value, enabled filter by that value?

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

For example:

```
Product.select("((100*(? - fabricated_at))/(maturity_at - fabricated_at)) as shelf_life", Time.now).
        where("((100*(today - fabricated_at))/(maturity_at - fabricated_at)) <= 70")
```

Should work with PostgreSQL and SQL Server

Tanks

Comment: If your code currently returns an error, please post it.  If it returns the wrong value, please post it along with the value you would like it to return.  I presume the "?" is a parameter reference.  What value are you using for the parameter?

Comment: The value for the parameter will always be the current date. 

The columns "fabricated_at" and "maturity_at" are of type "datetime" I need to transform them into numerical values ​​in order to calculate the percentage. 

Actually I can't do this calculation, because when I do "(maturity_at - fabricated_at)" the return is a interval, but I wish it were a numeric value.

Comment: Use `current_date` instead of `?` if it's always the current date. That's an SQL keyword that always produces the current date on the DB server. As for the interval, use `extract`, or (if you only want whole days) cast to `date` before subtracting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made a function to solve my problem, but it is only for PostgreSQL. If any customer using sql-server will have to do another function. Does anyone know how to make this function to PostgreSQL and for SQL Server?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teste(fabricacao timestamp, validade timestamp, data_base  timestamp) RETURNS float AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF DATE_PART('day', fabricacao -  validade) >= 0 THEN 
      return 0;
    ELSEIF data_base <= fabricacao THEN 
      return 0;     
    ELSEIF data_base <= validade THEN 
      return (100 * DATE_PART('day', data_base - fabricacao  )) / DATE_PART('day', validade  - fabricacao ); 
    ELSE 
      return 100; 
    END IF;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```